# VB.Net Properly shutdown an asynchronous socket server running on a background worker

Tags: vb.net, sockets, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have a Class called SocketSvr which handles an asynchronous socket server. It is called via the BackgroundWorker from my main form. Basically, I just want it to display my socket data information inside a textbox in the main form, and have a server start/stop button available on the main form to do those things.

Here is the code from Form1.vb:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents Socketsvr As New SocketSvr

    Private Sub ToggleServerButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToggleServerButton.Click

        If ToggleServerButton.Text = "Stop Server" Then
            ToggleServerButton.Text = "Start Server"
            Socketsvr.StopServer()
        Else
            ToggleServerButton.Text = "Stop Server"
            Socketsvr.StartServer()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateOutput_Event(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal text As String) Handles Socketsvr.UpdateOutput
        Me.ServerOutputTextbox.AppendText(text + vbCrLf)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The above is very simple, basically calls the StartServer() or StopServer() function. The event below is a Raised event which I am using to update the textbox via an invoked event from the background process.

Below is some of the code for Socketsvr.vb -- I remove irrelevant code to minimize blating of post.

```
Public Sub StopServer()
    bw.CancelAsync()
    allDone.Set()
End Sub 'StopServer

Public Sub StartServer()
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub 'StartServer

Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
    ' Data buffer for incoming data.
    Dim bytes() As Byte = New [Byte](1023) {}

    ' Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
    Dim ipHostInfo As New IPHostEntry
    ipHostInfo.AddressList = New IPAddress() _
        {New IPAddress(New [Byte]() {127, 0, 0, 1})}
    Dim ipAddress As IPAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList(0)
    Dim localEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8888)

    ' Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Dim listener As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

    ' Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1)
    listener.Bind(localEndPoint)
    listener.Listen(100)
    While True
        ' If cancellation is pending, shut down server
        If bw.CancellationPending Then
            Out("Server stopped at " + DateTime.Now.ToString())
            Exit While
        End If
        Out("Server started at " + DateTime.Now.ToString())
        ' Set the event to nonsignaled state.
        allDone.Reset()

        Try
            ' Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            listener.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptCallback), listener)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

        ' Wait until a connection is made and processed before continuing.
        allDone.WaitOne()
    End While
End Sub
```

I am uncertain how to properly shut down requests from the client when the StopServer() function is run. In the code above, I place a cancellation queue for the background process. The funny thing is that once StopServer() is run, it will accept one more connection, then stop accepting thereafter.

If I remove the following line from the code above:

```
listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1)
```

-- it crashes when I attempt to start the server a second time (complaining that I cannot reuse the socket, obviously) My guess is that I need to add something to the bw.CancellationPending call on the background worker?

Any insight would be appreciated, please let me know if more information is required from my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really like MSDN's example code because it uses a while loop that makes you think it's necessary; if it were necessary, then you would actually need to listen on another thread. Luckily, you don't need to use a `BackgroundWorker`, and you can easily do everything outside of a while loop without locking down the UI thread.

First, create a `Shared` method (to go along with the other shared callbacks and methods) called `Accept(Socket)` that will do the `Socket.BeginAccept`. Another method is easier because it will be run in two places, and you may later find the need to catch exceptions. Somewhere in your main `Form`, after binding the `IPEndPoint` and listening, you'll add your first call to `Accept`, providing the socket used for listening.

I would also recommend creating a `Receive(Socket)` method, where the socket is the newly connected client obtained in `AcceptCallback`. This will also improve organization because more code than just `BeginReceive` will be there, such as catching exceptions.

In your `AcceptCallback` method, after you do your `Receive`, you'll once again call `Accept`. This will continuously loop between `Accept` and `AcceptCallback`. In order to break this loop to stop listening, just call the `Socket.Close` method, set the socket field to Nothing, and catch these exceptions:

- `SocketException` (which is really unrelated to Close)
- `ObjectDisposedException` (since Close is a dispose)
- `NullReferenceException` (an occasional race condition will occur where a nullity (Nothing) check will pass but, just after that, the Socket will be disposed and set to null)

In your `StopServer` method, remember to set the Socket to Nothing (after closing the socket), which will signal that the socket has been disposed. You should also check to see that the listener is not Nothing before running any methods on it (which would be your `Accept` and `AcceptCallback` methods), making sure to catch `NullReferenceExceptions` for that occasional race condition.

Here's a basic model as to what your `Accept` method will look like. This is a similar model to the rest of the code, though.

```
Private Shared Sub AcceptCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim listener As Socket = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, Socket)

    If listener Is Nothing Then Return

    Try
        Dim newClient As Socket = listener.EndAccept(ar)

        Receive(newClient)
    Catch ex1 As SocketException
        Return
    Catch ex2 As ObjectDisposedException
        Return
    Catch ex3 As NullReferenceException
        Return
    End Try

    Accept(listener)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- still trying to wrap my head around it as I am very inexperienced with VB.Net - Will get back to you soon and see how it all works out. Have a +1 in the interim and will mark as answered once I have it working :)

Comment: i would also like to do the same thing, wpf ui for socket server based on microsoft async server sample. i would appreciate it someone could provide modified code in c#.

Comment: since i cant edit comment that i written, here a edited duplicate.i would also like to do the same thing, wpf ui for socket server based on microsoft async server sample. i would appreciate it someone could provide modified code in c#. i have some experience in c# but little network programming experience. or, if its bothering, could you point me to recommended async socket server implementation in wpf? thanks.